# Change Cookie expiry date - HTTP

Tags: html, django, http, cookies

**I need to change the expiry date of a Cookie that I occasionally set.**

More precisely I would like to refresh the expiry date to +1 hour.

---

**This is how I set the cookie**

```
Set-Cookie: test=123; Expires=Wed, 02 Feb 2011 12:00:00 GMT
```

Setting the cookie again adds another cookie with the same name :S

---

**Any ideas?**

Comment: How was that cookie originally defined?

Comment: That's not how you set the cookie - what code are you actually using to do it?

Comment: @Daniel: need to set a cookie with expiry date, and then refresh the expiry date when needed. `I'm using the expiry date as a timeout.`

Comment: What does that mean? What bit of Python did you use to set the above cookie?

Answer (score 3):

You can only overwrite a cookie if you use the same parameters (i.e. *Domain*, *Path*, *Secure*, and *HTTPOnly*).

So to overwrite your current cookie, you need to set it from the same domain and path.

Comment: Does the path really need to be exactly the same?

Comment: @RadiantHex: Yes, at least the resulting path needs to be the same: “Instances of the same path and name will overwrite each other, with the latest instance taking precedence.”

Answer (score 1):

If the match is present and unique, this works to set expiration to end of session:

```
document.cookie="meteor_login_token="+/meteor_login_token=([^;]*)/.exec(document.cookie)[1]+";path=/"
```

Comment: For anyone who doesn't follow the code, here is a simpler example to change the expiration from 20000 seconds after the cookie was first set to 1000 seconds from the new time it is set, ie, to change the expiration time of an existing cookie: [original:] document.cookie= "blah=foobar; max-age=20000; path=/somepath"  ...[and to reset the date later:] document.cookie= "blah=foobar; max-age=1000; path=/somepath" ... In the code above, no max-age was added so that makes the cookie a session cookie, but it retains the old value (and is invoked via old name and old path).